# Python Hex-String - Add space every x characters

Tags: python

I have a string in python, that looks like this: str = '02001400ce01', which is in hex: 0x02, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00,0xce, 0x01. I would like now to make the string to:

str = '02 00 14 00 ce 01'

How can I do this?

Comment: Part about hex values just makes your question more confusing.

Comment: `from textwrap import wrap; s = '02001400ce01'; print(" ".join(wrap(s, 2)))`

Answer (score 0):

This code will work.

```
str = '02001400ce01'
offset = 0
for i in range(len(str)):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        offset += 1 
        #insert a space at position i
        str = str[:i+offset] + ' ' + str[i+offset:]
print(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```py
string = '02001400ce01'
str_space = ' '.join(s1 + s2 for s1, s2 in zip(string[::2], string[1::2]))
```

Output:

```
'02 00 14 00 ce 01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `map` and `range` to generate the string.

`" ".join(list(map(lambda y: x[y:y+2],range(0,len(x),2))))`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).